# Show that a certain subset of $C[0,1]$ is not closed.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

Show that $\mathcal{F} = \{F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt : f\in C[0,1], \|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1\}$ is not closed as a subset of $C[0,1]$

To do this I was going to show that a sequence of functions in $\mathcal{F}$ converges to a function that is not in $\mathcal{F}$.  In particular I have a candidate function:

$$f_{n}(x) =\Bigg\{  
\begin{array}{11}
0, & x\in [0, \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}] \\
1 + n(x - \frac{1}{2}), & x \in [\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{2}] \\
1, & x \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1]
\end{array}
$$

What I wanted to do was show that this function converges to the characteristic function:

$$\chi_{[\frac{1}{2}, 1]} = \Bigg\{ 
\begin{array}{11}
0, & x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]\\
1,& x \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1]
\end{array}$$

Now here is where I am having some trouble. I've established that $f_{n}(x)$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$, so that is fine. But my idea was to show that $f_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly to $\chi_{[\frac{1}{2}, 1]}$. But IF it did converge uniformly that would mean that $\chi_{[\frac{1}{2}, 1]}$ was continuous. Which it is not. o I'm thinking I have to show pointwise convergence. To do this as I write it out now I'm realizing what could be done, I would have to split my question into two cases:

**Case 1:**

$x_{0} \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$, where $x_{0}$ is a fixed term.

Then $$\|f_{n}(x) - \chi_{[\frac{1}{2}, 1]}\| = \|1 + n(x - \frac{1}{2}) - 0\| = \|1 + n(x - \frac{1}{2})\|$$

**Case 2:**

$x_{0} \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1]$

Then $$\|f_{n}(x) - \chi_{[\frac{1}{2}, 1]}\| = \|1 - 1\| = 0$$

And then as I mentioned previously, this is converging to a discontinuous function so my set $\mathcal{F}$ is not closed.

Is this the right way to think and approach this problem?

**Edit:** Should I use single absolute value bars to distinguish from unifrom convergence?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten you're wanting to deal with convergence of $\int_0^x f_n(x)\,dx$.

You presumably need to show uniform convergence of $\int_0^x f_n(t)\,dt,$ which is $L^1$ convergence of $f_n$

Comment: I  examined the trouble point. In particular $\lim_{{x \to \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}^{-}}}f_{n}(x) = 0 = \lim_{{x \to \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}^{-+}}}f_{n}(x)$, and same idea for the other point $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Do I have to worry about the integrals? I thought if I established that $f_{n}(x)$ was discontinous in itself that the would be enough. @BrianMoehring, also the type of convergence was throwing me off as well. I know the set is using $\|f\|_{\infty}$ convergence, but if I could establish that sort of convergence it would mean I am converging to a continuous function.

Comment: Yes, you still need to consider the integrals, because that is where the convergence is defined as uniform convergence.  It also allows to you phrase the problem in a different way as "A uniform limit of continuously differentiable functions $F_n$ with $\|F_n'\|_\infty \leq 1$ may not be continuously differentiable"

Comment: If I'm interpreting this correctly. Say I establish this uniform convergence with the integrals, then I could apply the integral convergence theorem and bring the limits inside the integrand and display that the function I get is not continuous?

Comment: Which integral convergence theorem are you referring to?

Comment: "If you have a sequence of functions $f_{n}$ that converge uniformly to a function $f$ on a compact interval, then $F_{n}(x) = \int_{c}^{x}f_{n}(t)dt \to F(x) = \int_{x}^{c}f(t)dt$....In other words: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f(x) = \int \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97289/discussion-between-brian-moehring-and-dc3rd).

Comment: Your sequence of functions $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly, so you can't use that.

Just write down your integrals $F_n(x),$ find the uniform limit $F(x)$ of _those_ functions, and note why $F'(x)$ is not differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

Every function in $\mathcal F$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$ by the FTC. But your $f_n$'s are not differentiable at $1/2,$ so they can't be in $\mathcal F.$

I did the problem this way: The functions $((x-1/2)^2+1/n)^{1/2}$ $\to |x-1/2|$ uniformly on $[0,1].$ This implies the functions

$$F_n(x)=\int_0^x\frac{t}{(t^2+1/n)^{1/2}}\,dt$$

converge uniformly to $|x-1/2|-1/2$ on $[0,1].$ Note that each $F_n$ is in $\mathcal F.$ Since $|x-1/2|-1/2$ is not differentiable at $1/2,$ it is not in $\mathcal F.$  It follows that $\mathcal F$ is not closed in $C[0,1].$